# Load sequence of PNGs into vtkImageData for 3D volume render using python

Tags: python, image, 3d, vtk

I have a sequence of about 100 PNG files containing 512x512 pre-segmented CAT scan data. I want to use vtk on Python to create a 3D model using marching cubes algorithm. The part that I don't know how to do is to load the sequence of PNG files and convert them to a single vtk pixel data object suitable for sending to the `vtkDiscreteMarchingCubes` algorithm.

I also think that I need to convert the pixel values of the PNG data because right now the data is in the alpha channel, so this needs to be converted into scalar data with values of zero and 1.

Comment: Sounds like you need to find an example file for the vtk input format, just to know what the png should be converted to... for example if i search for vtk slices i on google i get pages like this: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/IO/ReadDICOMSeries which seems to be an example,im not goint to read it, if you find the slice data format that loads to vtk i can help with conversion.

Answer (score 1):

use vtkPNGreader and load in individual slices and then populate a vtkImageData which you can define the dimensions as  and for each z-slice or image fill the image data form the output of the reader into your vtkImageData.

Rough pseudocode - not checked for bugs :)

```
import vtk
from vtk.util import numpy_support

pngfiles = glob.glob('*.png')

png_reader = vtk.vtkPNGReader()
png_reader.SetFileName(pngfiles[0])
x,y = png_reader.GetOutput().GetDimensions()

data_3d = np.zeros([x,y,len(pngfiles)])

for i,p in enumerate(png):
    png_reader.SetFileName(pngfiles[0])
    png_reader.Update()
    img_data = png_reader.GetOutput()
    data_3D[:,:,i] = numpy_support.vtk_to_numpy(img_data)

#save your 3D numpy array out.
data_3Dvtk = numpy_support.numpy_to_vtk(data_3D)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone stumbles on here looking for another way to do this only using vtk, you can use `vtkImageAppend` class.

```
def ReadImages(files):
    reader = vtk.vtkPNGReader()
    image3D = vtk.vtkImageAppend()
    image3D.SetAppendAxis(2)
    
    for f in files:
        reader.SetFileName(f)
        reader.Update()
        t_img = vtk.vtkImageData()
        t_img.DeepCopy(reader.GetOutput())
        image3D.AddInputData(t_img)

    image3D.Update()

    return image3D.GetOutput()
```

for converting the data you can take a look at what the output of t_img.GetPointData().GetArray('PNGImage') gives and see if it is the expected value.